# How to return on the same page after submitting a form in php.?

Tags: php, mysql, http

I am making an e-commerce website where I have lots of products. If a user goes to any product items page and submits any form there then they should come on the same page.

So, how to come on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You All. I Got My Answer

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` will give the current URL with query strings.

Like my page is '**`products.php?Product=20`**'

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; =>/products.php?Product=20
```

So, we can directly use this in header location.

Answer (score 2):

On the formular target page set:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/same_page');
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave `action` attribute of `form` blank. Like so:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Or

```
<form action="#" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this   :

```
 header('Location: filename.php);
```

If you get any `$_POST` errors put it in a condition: `if(isset[$_POST])`

Comment: Add an ' to 'Location: filename.php

Answer (score 0):

On your opening form tag add

> action="submit.php"

- then once it goes to that page when the submit button is hit add this
  to the bottom of that php page:

> header("Location: success.html OR success.php");

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit various forms on same page and then go back to the page where the form is submitted, you must also send the form URL of the page where it was sent, preferably in a hidden element. And after processing form redirect to URL stored in hidden.